# What does the right arrow do in this code: "Ramaze.start :port => 80"

Tags: ruby, syntax

```
Ramaze.start :port => 80
```

If my understanding is correct, the line above is a method call in Ruby and you could also write it as:

```
Ramaze.start(:port => 80)
```

But in either case, what does it mean when you put the => character between the symbol :port and the number 80?

Is that a way of creating a Hash?

When the Ramaze.start method receives the method parameters, what is the type of the argument?

Is it received as a single argument key-value pair?

Or it received as two arguments: :port and 80?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It creates a hashmap where the symbol :port is the key and the value is 80.

Answer (score 4):

When you have a method where the last parameter is a hash, the braces are optional.

Example:

```
def foo options
  # ...
end
```

Then this is allowed:

```
foo :bar => :baz
```

But if you have:

```
def foo options, say_hi
  # ...
  if say_hi
    puts 'Hi!'
  end
end
```

Then you cannot do:

```
foo :bar => :baz, true
```

But you'd have to call it like:

```
foo({:bar => :baz}, true)
```

I can't figure out why the parentheses are required in that instance, though, but they seem to be.

Answer (score -7):

It's called a lambda.  It's a short way of declaring a method.  For instance, I can say myBirthday => myBirthday.Where(some value).  Notice how you are passing in the object itself into the shortened function.  In your case, you're passing in a port, giving it a value of 80, then returning the port object.

Comment: No. No no no. This is incorrect and misleading. See the accepted answer.